# Can someone diagnose the issue with my Haskell code?

Tags: list, if-statement, haskell, recursion, iteration

I get the feeling I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about the way in which Haskell is written. My code is intended to serve as an evaluation function for a primitive AI for the game Othello. Essentially I want my code to cycle through a list of pieces, each piece represented by a tuple composed of a Position (Int, Int) and a Col (Colour, either Black or White), and given a prospective move identify how good the move is.

The way I'm judging the value of a move is based on a few factors:

- Is there a piece on the board in a straight line from the intended position of the same colour?
- If the previous requirement is true, how many pieces of the opposite colour are inbetween those two pieces?

Since Haskell has no loop structures it seems like I need to implement this recursively, as such my code is as follows:

```
eval :: Position -> [(Position, Col)] -> Col -> GameState -> Int -> Int
eval move pieces moveColour gameState score = do
                                                let moveX = fst move
                                                let moveY = snd move
                                                let piece = head(pieces)
                                                let pieceColour = snd piece
                                                let pieceX = fst fst piece
                                                let pieceY = snd fst piece
                                                if (moveColour == pieceColour) then
                                                  if (moveX == pieceX) then
                                                    if (moveY > pieceY) then
                                                      let newScore = score + (countOtherColour 0 moveY pieceY (pieces gameState) moveColour 0)
                                                      --recurse
                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                        return newScore
                                                      else
                                                        return eval move tail(pieces) moveColour gameState newScore
                                                    else
                                                      let newScore = score + (countOtherColour 0 pieceY moveY (pieces gameState) moveColour 0)
                                                      --recurse
                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                        return newScore
                                                      else
                                                        return eval move tail(pieces) moveColour gameState newScore
                                                  else
                                                    if (moveY == pieceY) then
                                                      if (moveX > pieceX) then
                                                        let newScore = score + (countOtherColour 1 moveX pieceX (pieces gameState) moveColour 0)
                                                        --recurse
                                                        if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                          return newScore
                                                        else
                                                          return eval move tail(pieces) moveColour gameState newScore
                                                      else
                                                        let newScore = score + (countOtherColour 1 pieceX moveX (pieces gameState) moveColour 0)
                                                        --recurse
                                                        if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                          return newScore
                                                        else
                                                          return eval move tail(pieces) moveColour gameState newScore
                                                    else
                                                      --recurse
                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                        return score
                                                      else
                                                        return eval move tail(pieces) moveColour gameState score
                                                else
                                                  --recurse
                                                  if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                    return score
                                                  else
                                                    return eval move tail(pieces) moveColour gameState score

countOtherColour :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [(Position, Col)] -> Col -> Int -> Int
countOtherColour xyFlag upper lower pieces turnColour score = do
                                                                --if xyFlag == 0 it's y aligned if 1 it's x aligned
                                                                let piece = head(pieces)
                                                                let pieceColour = other (snd piece)
                                                                let x = fst fst piece
                                                                let y = snd fst piece
                                                                if (pieceColour == turnColour) then
                                                                  if (xyFlag == 0) then
                                                                    if (upper > x && x > lower) then
                                                                      let newScore = score+1
                                                                      --recurse
                                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                                        return newScore
                                                                      else
                                                                        return countOtherColour xyFlag upper lower tail(pieces) turnColour newScore
                                                                    else
                                                                      --recurse
                                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                                        return score
                                                                      else
                                                                        return countOtherColour xyFlag upper lower tail(pieces) turnColour score
                                                                  else
                                                                    if (upper > y && y > lower) then
                                                                      let newScore = score+1
                                                                      --recurse
                                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                                        return newScore
                                                                      else
                                                                        return countOtherColour xyFlag upper lower tail(pieces) turnColour newScore
                                                                    else
                                                                      --recurse
                                                                      if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                                        return score
                                                                      else
                                                                        return countOtherColour xyFlag upper lower tail(pieces) turnColour score
                                                                else
                                                                  --recurse
                                                                  if (tail(pieces) == []) then
                                                                    return score
                                                                  else
                                                                    return countOtherColour xyFlag upper lower tail(pieces) turnColour score
```

However, this code does not compile. I get a "parse error on "if"" on the first line that reads:

```
if (tail(pieces) == []) then
```

This leads me to believe that something fundamental about the way in which I've structured this code is faulty. I would like to clarify I'm **NOT** looking for someone to solve the implementation for me, only for someone to explain to me how my implementation is flawed, and a general guide on how I can implement recursion within the correct way to structure my code.

If you've read this far thank you, and I look forward to reading your replies.

Comment: One comment: your code seems far more verbose and complicated than should be necessary. Here’s some advice on what you might do to it to clean it up a bit: (1) You have far more indentation than necessary. You don’t need to indent the `do` block that far — just two or four spaces is sufficient. (2) You have lots of duplication; you can try to reduce this duplication by moving all the repeated bits into their own function.

Comment: @bradrn Thanks for the advice, I will sort the indentation, but I'm not sure if you notice, but depending on the context for the recursive part (the part which has the duplication) the recursion has to be called in a different way. I'm unsure how I can move this to its own function while maintaining the ability to slightly change the way in which it's called depending on the context.

Comment: I did notice that. That doesn’t matter in terms of separating it out into another function: just give the changing bits as parameters to that function, and call that function with different parameters every time.

Answer (score 4):

When `let` is outside a `do`, it requires an `in`, for example:

```
-- correct
x =
    let a = 5
    in a + 37

-- incorrect
x =
    let a = 5
    a + 37
```

So when your `if` comes right after a `let`, there should be an `in` right in front of it:

```
let newScore = score+1 
-- recurse
in if (tail(pieces) == []) then
       ...
```

---

Besides this, there are quite a few other things in your code that could be cleaner. I won't go through all of them, will just give a few examples.

One example is that multiple `let` bindings in a row don't need a separate `let` for each:

```
x =
    let a = 5
        b = 37
    in a + b
```

Similarly, the condition of `if` doesn't need parens, and neither do function calls:

```
if tail pieces == [] then
```

And while we're at it: test for empty list via the `null` function instead of comparing `== []`:

```
if null (tail pieces) then
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't appear to mention the most fundamental misunderstanding here: using a `do` block for a function that's supposed to result in an `Int`.

Comment: Your first "correct" example is incorrect, because it uses two `let`s but only one `in`. I'm not sure whether you meant to remove the second `let` (normal Haskell style), or add a second `in` (to delay showing off multiple bindings).

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm embarrassed to say, I simply hadn't noticed it. There's quite a bit there :-)

Comment: `do` notation is used for monads. It's a syntactic sugar for operator `>>=` (check out [the wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)). Type `Int` is not a monad and does not have a `>>=` operator defined, so `do` notation doesn't work. But it's a bit more complicated, because the type `a -> b` (for any `a` and `b`) is, in fact, a monad, and _does_ have operator `>>=` defined, so the compiler may consider this whole function implemented in the monad `Int -> Int` and give you strange-looking errors as a result.

Comment: The general rule is: never assume, always make sure you actually _know_ what things mean before using them.